# Модули python для sftp

Tags: python, python-3.x, sftp

Есть ли модули python для подключения к sftp серверу, кроме paramiko и от него зависимых?

Comment: а чем парамико не устроил?

Comment: на такие вопросы («библиотека для языка X по тематике Y») веб-поисковики хорошо отвечают. Без указания конкретной задачи (критерия по которой одну библиотеку по сравнению с другой можно было бы выбрать), вопрос не слишком полезен (на английском SO такие вопросы вообще недопустимы).  Можно улучшить вопрос поставив конкретную задачу, к примеру, «быстро скопировать файл на 1000 узлов по sftp». Указав код на paramiko, который медленно работает и описав характеристики окружения (размер файла, скорости сети, дисков, возможности установки ПО -- может вам bittorrent больше подойдёт)

Comment: `parallel-ssh`  поверх libssh2 может работать.

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите:
https://bitbucket.org/dundeemt/pysftp/src

Может быть подойдёт. Правда давно не обновлялось.